# Trouble populating form using ajax Get

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, xml-parsing

I am attempting (still) to populating a jQuery mobile form with a remote XML by creating a select from the "Project_ID" field and using that to populate the other form fields according to the XML.

I think that the issue lies in the way I am trying to populate the select as with JQuery mobile a popup is created that I think may need to be refreshed?

Further, I am getting an error when I try to debug "Object doesn't support this property or method" at the line:       Workplans = xml.find('Workplan');

My script

```js
$('#btnxml').click(function () {
  getXML();
});

function getXML() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "WorkplanReview.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (xml) {

        var select = $('#Project_ID'),
            Workplans = xml.find('Workplan');

        $(xml).find(Workplan).each(function () {
            var Project_ID = $(this).find('Project_ID').text();
            select.append("<option>" + Project_ID + "</option>");
        });

        $("#Project_ID").change(function () {
            var selectedIndex = $('#Project_ID option').index($('#Project_ID option:selected')),
                Workplan = $(Workplans[selectedIndex]);

            $('#WorkplanRecordNumber').val(Workplan.find('WorkplanRecordNumber').text());
            $('#Area').val(Workplan.find('Area').text());
            $('#Station_Name').val(Workplan.find('Station_Name').text());
            $('#Station_Description').val(Workplan.find('Station_Description').text());
            $('#Station_ID').val(Workplan.find('Station_ID').text());
            $('#Latitude').val(Workplan.find('Latitude').text());
            $('#Longitude').val(Workplan.find('Longitude').text());
            $('#HUC_8_Digit').val(Workplan.find('HUC_8_Digit').text());
            $('#County').val(Workplan.find('County').text());
        }).trigger('change');

     }
  });
}
```

My HTML

```html
<input type="button" id="btnxml" value="XML" />Workplan Number
<input type="text" name="WorkplanRecordNumber" id="WorkplanRecordNumber">Area
<input type="text" name="Area" id="Area">Project ID
<select id="Project_ID" name="Project_ID">
  <option>Loading</option>
</select>Station Name:
<input type="text" name="Station_Name" id="Station_Name">Station Description:
<input type="text" name="Station_Description" id="Station_Description">Station ID
<input type="text" name="Station_ID" id="Station_ID">
<label class="huc-label" for="HUC_8_Digit">HUC</label>
<select class="select_huc" id="HUC_8_Digit" name="HUC_8_Digit" data-iconpos="left" data-icon="grid">
  <option>Select</option>
</select>
<label class="county-label" for="County">County</label>
<select class="select_county" id="County" name="County" data-iconpos="left" data-icon="grid">
  <option>County</option>
</select>Latitude:
<input type="number" id="Latitude" name="Latitude" value="">Longitude:
<input type="number" id="Longitude" name="Longitude" value="">
```

I know you folks can help me and I thank you in advance!

Comment: if you're adding items to a selectmenu, use `.selectmenu('refresh')` to enhance it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery extends methods like `find` to jQuery objects. `xml` is a string, and is not yet converted into a jQuery object. You need to do something like this:

```
$(xml).find('Workplan');
```

Or I recommend re-using the object like this:

```
success: function(xml) {
    var $xml = $(xml);
    ...
    $xml.find('Workplan');
```

---

Let's see what else we can do:

```
$(function() { // Make sure all of this is wrapped in document-ready

    var Workplans; // this isn't global, but is referenced in other methods

    $('#btnxml').click(function () {
      getXML();
    });

    // Event handlers should only ever be set up once.
    $("#Project_ID").change(function () {
       var selectedIndex = $('#Project_ID option').index($('#Project_ID option:selected')),
            Workplan = $(Workplans[selectedIndex]);

        $('#WorkplanRecordNumber').val(Workplan.find('WorkplanRecordNumber').text());
        $('#Area').val(Workplan.find('Area').text());
        $('#Station_Name').val(Workplan.find('Station_Name').text());
        $('#Station_Description').val(Workplan.find('Station_Description').text());
        $('#Station_ID').val(Workplan.find('Station_ID').text());
        $('#Latitude').val(Workplan.find('Latitude').text());
        $('#Longitude').val(Workplan.find('Longitude').text());
        $('#HUC_8_Digit').val(Workplan.find('HUC_8_Digit').text());
        $('#County').val(Workplan.find('County').text());
    });

    function getXML() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "WorkplanReview.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {

            Workplans = $(xml).find('Workplan'); // modifies a higher scope

            Workplans.each(function () {
                var Project_ID = $(this).find('Project_ID').text();
                $("#Project_ID").append("<option>" + Project_ID + "</option>");
            });

            $("#Project_ID").trigger('change');

         }
      });
    }
});
```

Comment: Took care of the error (thank you!) but it still doesn't work

Comment: I've edited my answer. The major issue was the `change` handlers being stacked multiple times. They don't replace eachother, they stack. I moved `Workplans` to an outer scope so it is accessible from the other methods.